# Create tensor of a sequence with a defined shape using TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

> Create a tensor Y of shape (2,3) having a sequence of numbers 12,15,18,...., 150

I tried using the below code

`tf.constant(np.arange(12,153,3),dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,shape=[2,3])`

I got an error saying the tensor with 47 elements cannot be converted into 6 elements.

I added the following third dimension in shape and it worked.

`tf.constant(np.arange(12,153,3),dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,shape=[8,2,3])`

How to proceed as the given question wants the sequence tensor to be in shape [2,3]?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As given in [tf.constant](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) documentation:

> If `value` is a list, then the length of the list must be less than or equal to the number of elements implied by the `shape` argument (if specified).

In your code, the `value` is the returned array from `np.arange(12,153,3)` containing 47 integers.

Now, when you specify `shape = [2,3]`, it implies that the length of the list you have provided as `value` is 2x3 = 6 which is not true because the array generated by `np.arange(12,153,3)` has the length = 47. In this case, you will get an error saying:

> ValueError: Too many elements provided. Needed at most 6, but received 47

On the other hand, when you specify `shape = [8,2,3]`, it implies that the length of the list you have provided as `value` is 8x2x3 = 48 which is also not true because the actual length is 47. It does not raise an error because the length of the list can be less than the number implied by the `shape` argument as it says in the documentation:

> In the case where the list length is less than the number of elements specified by shape, the last element in the list will be used to fill the remaining entries.

So, it is not possible to shape a sequence of 47 elements to [2,3]

Comment: Thanks Is there an alternative where the last element in the list be 0 if length of list less than shape?

Comment: @tendo I do not completely understand your question but check [this code](https://pastebin.com/H3GzTvzF) if it helps.

Comment: I got your point but can we make a sequence whose length is less than the shape and the remaining elements padded with 0?

Comment: just add a zero at the end of your sequence so, when it is passed as the `value` in `tf.constant`, the remaining entries will be filled with zero if the length of the sequence is less than the number of elements implied by the `shape`.

Comment: Ok got it thanks